# Function calls with loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why when I click on my buttons there are always 100 in console log? And how I can fix this?

```
function SampleFunction(param){
    console.log(param);
}

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $("#btn-" + i).on('click',function(e){
        SampleFunction(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: try something like this `$("#btn-" + i).on('click', SampleFunction );`, than use event.target in the function like this `function SampleFunction(e){ elem = e.target; console.log( elem.id ); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `let` keyword

```
for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    $("#btn-" + i).on('click',function(e){
        SampleFunction(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: @nicholas-kyriakides, thanks for down-voting and deleting your own comment T_T

Comment: @Anton, please note that `let` is es6, you need to check browser compatibility. probably ie11  doesnt support it

Answer (score 0):

Pure js approach

```js
let allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(i=0;i<allButtons.length;i++) {
   allButtons[i].onclick = getPosition;
}


function getPosition() {
  let position = Array.from(allButtons).indexOf(this) + 1;
  console.log(`you clicked button at position ${position}`)
}
```

```html
<button id="button-1">1</button>
<button id="button-2">2</button>
<button id="button-3">3</button>
<button id="button-4">4</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Rajkumar. With buttons it works pretty well, but using with other dom elements like table rows will cause some trouble.

Comment: But your problem statement said buttons , hence I didnt focus on other aspects;